# Objective-C SQLIte Database Vs. Query Statements

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I have an iPad application that runs a SQLite database. I use FMDatabase as the wrapper and it all has worked really good, up until the point I started getting large amounts of data.

Once per day, my users will have to download a large file from our server. It's a SQL script that should be executed on the iPad to update the records/tables that are there. This file has become VERY large and it doesn't work as expected.

With FMDatabase, I have to read the file into an NSString then process the SQL statment. This is where I think the bottleneck is... I think the amount of data being stored into memory is too large. Here is my script:

```
 BOOL isFinishedSyncing = [db executeUpdate:[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL]];
```

I want to either run this file direcly, but I am not sure that is possible.

The only other solution I have is to build the database and just replace the database that is stored on the iPad... But I wasn't sure if providing just an SQL file like this is the same as building a database...

I recently tried the following function:

```
+(BOOL)execFileFromDatabase: (sqlite3 *)db sqlFilePath:(NSString*)filepath{

NSError *error;
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".read %@", filepath];

if(error){
    return NO;
}

char* execError;
int x = sqlite3_exec(db, [content UTF8String], nil, nil, &execError);
if(execError){
    NSLog(@"DB: --- %s", execError);
}

return x == SQLITE_OK;

 }
```

I get this response:

```
 DB: --- near ".": syntax error
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Having the user download an updated db file is far simpler and faster than running a massive SQL update. Download the new db file to a tmp location, close the current db. Move the new one into place, and open the new one. Done. Far more efficient.

Comment: I figured as much, but just providing the actual SQL inside a file named... whatever.db, will that work? Or does it need to be compile somewhere?

Comment: All you need is the database file. That's it. Nothing needs to be compiled.

Comment: Not sure that I am doing this right, but I have a load of SQL queries to create tables and insert data into those tables... How would I actually convert this to a usable database?

Comment: Use the `sqlite3` command line to create a database file from the queries.

Comment: I ended up trying that... I modified my original post with the code and response.